# Unable to connect to Splunk Enterprise on Azure

Tags: azure, splunk

I have deployed Splunk Enterprise app on Azure and it has given me a DNS to connect to Splunk as http://{domainname}.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com but when i am using this to connect, i am receiving "This site can’t be reached" error. Please help !
Thanks in advance

U

Answer (score 0):

have you tried http://{domainname}.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:8000, https://{domainname}.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com or https://{domainname}.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:8000

Have you made sure Splunk is running? Are  there any firewalls you need to configure?